# Find text and copy row to other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I have a list of data in Google Sheets that I want to use to extract certain names based upon another list.

Following code works to point me out on what row the search_string is:

```
function searchString(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var search_string = "searchname1"
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search_string)
  var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("search row: " + search_row)
}
```

I want to find out how I can add multiple search_strings like below. Its quite a list.
I tried array brackets but that gives me an error of NULL.

```
function searchString(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var search_string = ("searchname1","searchname2")
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(search_string)
  var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("search row: " + search_row)

}
```

Then instead of showing me an alert I want to copy the rows that are found to a new sheet.
In the subsequential order of the array of search_strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to copy the rows where the strings appear (for the first time) in the source sheet to a target sheet.

- You can include all the strings you want to search in the `search_strings` array.
- Iterate over each string to find the first row it appears and add that row to the `rows` array.

Then you can get all the data from the source sheet and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) only the rows that are part of the `rows` list:

```
var data = source_sheet.getDataRange()
         .getValues().filter((_,i)=>rows.includes(i+1));
```

Finally copy the data to the target sheet.

### Solution:

```
function searchString(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change the name
  const target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'); // change the name     
  const search_strings = ["searchname1","searchname2"]; // add your strings to search
  const rows = [];

  search_strings.forEach(search_string=>{                    
         let textFinder = source_sheet.createTextFinder(search_string);
         try{
            let search_row = textFinder.findNext().getRow();
            rows.push(search_row);     
         } catch(e){}
  });
  const data = source_sheet.getDataRange()
             .getValues().filter((_,i)=>rows.includes(i+1));

  if(data.length>0){
    target_sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Little following question when I try this with 10 names it works. When I paste my full array. I get the following error.

14:45:04 Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRow' of null
(anoniem) @ Code.gs:11
searchString @ Code.gs:9

Comment: @QuintenDeWilde hmm I think you put some strings that are not part of your source sheet . I will fix the code later to consider this case. You can add an if condition like `if(!textFinder)` right after `textFinder` and put the next two lines inside that if block.  If you can't do it yourself I will adjust my answer in a couple of hours. I need to test it myself to make sure it works like that.

Comment: I tried the if(!textFinder) but got other issues of syntax. I'm guessing I'm not implementing it correctly?

Comment: @QuintenDeWilde I updated my answer. I don't know if it works I can't test it right now.

Comment: Sorry in changing this a new error has risen: 
15:04:06 Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
searchString @ Code.gs:17

How do I define the length?

Comment: @QuintenDeWilde put `if(data.length>0){target...}` . Like I said I can't test it now so please wait a couple of hours or simply ask a new question if you are in a hurry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229162/discussion-between-quinten-de-wilde-and-marios).

Comment: @QuintenDeWilde I updated my code. Let me know if it worked.